# Can I disable specific widget sizes in SwiftUI iOS 14

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget, ios14

Do we need to have all 3 system sizes available for widgets in iOS 14?

Is it possible to disable SystemLarge/Medium?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the answer

```
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
        TestWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
    }
    .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium])
    .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
    .description("This is an example widget.")
}
```

You can add **.supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium])** in the **@main** functions